# realizar consulta con tres tablas en Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Yo tengo tres tablas que son las siguientes **users**, **mapas**, **marcadores**

- Un usuario tiene varios mapas
- un mapa tiene varios marcadores

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es mostrar los marcadores que pertenecen a los mapas del usuario que ha iniciado sesión.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la función en el controllador en la que estoy trabajando:

```
public function index()
        {
            $mapas = Mapa::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
            $marcadores = Marcador::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('mapa_id');
            return view('user.marcadores.index', compact('marcadores'));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es cargar los `marcadores` cuando buscas los mapas y luego extraer estos para devolverlos a la vista.

```
class Mapa extends Model
{
    /**
     * Obtener los marcadores.
     */
    public function marcadores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Marcadores::class);
    }
}
```

Luego, en tu controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $marcadores = Mapa::with('marcadores')
                     ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                     ->where('user_id', auth()->id()) // equivalente a auth()->user()->id
                     ->get()  // hasta acá ya cargamos los mapas con sus marcadores
                     ->flatMap(function ($mapa) {
                         return $mapa->marcadores;
                     });    // con esto estamos extrayendo los marcadores y compactando el array


    return view('user.marcadores.index', ['marcadores' => $marcadores]);
}
```

---

Importante notar que `->get()` retornará una colección de objetos. Esta colección es una instancia de la clase [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections), la cual permite utilizar todos estos [útiles métodos](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods) con los cuales se puede mapear/transformar/extraer datos, etc. Es debido a esto que utilicé [FlatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatmap).

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes las relaciones establecidas en el modelo puedes hacer la query así:

```
class Mapa extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function marcadores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('TuModeloMarcadores');
    }
}
```

`Mapa::with('marcadores')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);`

Y luego accedes a los marcadores del mapa así

```
foreach ($mapas as $mapa) {
    $mapa->marcadores
}
```